# How to make an singleton instance visible everywhere using CDI?

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, singleton, cdi

I have an application. Each user corresponds to the entity "Client". During the session, the user works with his entity.

I have JAX-RS + EJB application. I want this entity to be visible and used in all services, as a singleton. I want to achieve it using CDI.

First, the user login to the application. After login, I want to get its entity from the base and assign it to a singleton, but I didn't succeed. I tried the `@Singleton` annotations (`javax.inject`), `@SessionScoped` and `@ApplicationScoped`.

How can I do it?

```
//Entity
@Entity
@SessionScope //or @Singlton/@ApplicationScope
class Client { fields }
```

---

```
//login service
@Inject 
Client client;
//After login I want to assign an entity from db[cleintEntity] 
//to entity which is available everywhere[client]
client = clientEntity;
```

I want to do this:

```
//some ejb
@Inject
Client client;
//use entity
```

I don't want to transmit a link to the instance throughout the application, but I want it to be available everywhere using CDI.

Or do I need to create a separate `ClientDAO`, which will be my singleton?

Comment: So you mean there is only a single instance of Client class for all your users? Since you're initializing it after login so it seems to be a user specific object, which means it's not a singleton or application scope.

Comment: @zaerymoghaddam No, I want to load entity into a singlton object while I(the user) work with it. For each session - by singleton object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, you must use the `@SessionScope`. The `@Singleton` and `@ApplicationScope` could be used if you wanted to have a single instance for all your users.

To solve your problem:

1. You want to instantiate the `Client` when user logs in. So when you're in the login service, this object is not instantiated yet, so you can't `@Inject` it into your login service and you should remember to remove the `@Inject` annotation.
2. You need to use the `@Produces` annotation. This annotation is used when you want to have control on the way your class is getting instantiated. When CDI container wants to find an implementation of the `Client` class, if it finds a method that returns `Client` and has `@Produces` annotation, it calls that method instead of just instantiating the `Client` itself. You should do your login business, then create an instance of `Client` and store it in your login service as a member variable. Then add a method in this class which returns that client object and annotate the method with `@Produces`. The final structure of your login service would be something like this:

```
    @SessionScope
    public class LoginService {
        private Client client;

        public void login(String username, String password) {
            //  implement login business

            //  if login is successful
            client = clientEntity;
        }

        @Produces
        @SessionScope
        public Client clientProducer() {
            return this.client;
        }
    }
```

You can also put the `@Produces` annotation on top of a field. In such cases, the CDI container will use the value stored on that field instead of calling a method.

```
    @SessionScope
    public class LoginService {
        @Produces
        @SessionScope
        private Client client;

        public void login(String username, String password) {
            //  implement login business

            //  if login is successful
            client = clientEntity;
        }
    }
```

Of course this should be considered as a sort of pseudocode. I don't know about all the details of your business. Maybe the way you're implementing the logic is completely wrong ;). But to solve this specific problem, the `@Produces` should work.

Comment: Thx, most likely this is what I needed. But why is there `@SessionScope` in `LoginService`?

Comment: As you'll going to store the `Client` instance in that variable, you should be sure that you wouldn't share your `LoginService` with other clients. So it should also be limited to the current session (current user). Otherwise you need to use a sort of a shared map/list of all such clients or put them in a sort of a cache/pool and access that pool in your producer method. Now that I think again, probably `@RequestScope` would also work. I think it worth to try it first.

Comment: @RequestScope life span is one HTTP-request. User makes more then 1 request in the application.

Comment: By the way, what about putting the Client object in httpSession? Wherever I need, I can inject httpSession and get Client from there.

Comment: I explain what I want to achieve - I want the user to be able to change some data about himself. In order not to make lots of requests to the database, I want to load the user's entity and work with it. At the end just make `em.persist`.

But I don't want to send the client object in the ejb, I want it to be available in all methods(probably using CDI).

Comment: OK. I think first of all a query to load a user from database is nothing that you should be worried about until it's going to have millions of request per minutes or have hundreds of millions of users in database. I mean you're maybe doing some overengineering. Second of all, it's not a good practice to store your entity in your session. It's a hibernate/jpa entity and it would be detached from database when your transaction ends. So you can't update it in your next query. Even if it doesn't throw an exception (for any reason) Hibernate will try to fetch it anyway to update its properties.

Comment: OK, got it. And yet I wouldn’t like to write jpql requests to the database all the time (they are long and inconvenient), but I would like to use getters/setters to change data.

If I declare an entity as simply @SessionScope, then it will not be available as a singleton(and for each user their own)? Cause I don’t want to use entity storage.

P.S. I think @SessionScope isn`t needed in LoginService. LoginServise is a rest-service.

Comment: By the way, I came up with a new version. I will have a singleton @SessionScope Client object that I will change. When the user clicks "confirm data change", I will update the data - I will get connection, find the entity in the database, and record the changes from the singleton to the entity. Is it working method?